# First parameter of direct_to_template?

Tags: django, view

I keep seeing calls to `direct_to_template` include a "request" argument as the first parameter. E.g.

`direct_to_template(request, 'template/url', template_values)`

However, the docs do not mention this first parameter. What is this request argument doing, and how is it allowed to be there?

[Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-direct-to-template)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`direct_to_template` is a view: all views always take the `request` as the first argument (note that the docs page is called "generic *views*"). Using that function as an alternative to render_to_response is a bit of a hack, really.

Also, 1.4 is very old and will only be supported for another few months; you should switch to the newer long-term support release, 1.8, in which the old functional generic views are removed. In this case though you should just use the `render` shortcut which has exactly the same signature.